# Узнать к какому типу относится символ

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, есть 2 строки, формат которых нужно проанализировать на похожесть.

Я хотел параллельно идти по 2-ум строкам и сравнивать принадлежность символа к конкретному типу (цифра, буква и т д).

Есть статические методы char, но они неудобны. Хотелось бы иметь чего-то, что возвращает перечисление.

Есть ли в .NET что-либо готовое или нужно пилить собственное решение, которое будет оборачивать статические методы char и возвращать перечисление?

Comment: Смысл делать перечисление? Если вы сравниваете 2 символа - напишите функцию, что принимает 2 символа и возвращает результат сравнения - в таком сценарии вроде никакой энум не нужен

Comment: @tym32167, мне показалось, что с перечислением работать удобнее...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такое перечисление уже есть: это [`UnicodeCategory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory(v=vs.110).aspx). Вы можете классифицировать символ при помощи [`CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6sx68ke(v=vs.110).aspx).

Например, вот такой код:

```
string s = "Это 2048, юбилейный выпуск!";
foreach (var c in s)
    Console.WriteLine($"Символ: {c}, категория: {CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c)}");
```

на моей машине выдаёт:

```
Символ: Э, категория: UppercaseLetter
Символ: т, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: о, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ:  , категория: SpaceSeparator
Символ: 2, категория: DecimalDigitNumber
Символ: 0, категория: DecimalDigitNumber
Символ: 4, категория: DecimalDigitNumber
Символ: 8, категория: DecimalDigitNumber
Символ: ,, категория: OtherPunctuation
Символ:  , категория: SpaceSeparator
Символ: ю, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: б, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: и, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: л, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: е, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: й, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: н, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: ы, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: й, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ:  , категория: SpaceSeparator
Символ: в, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: ы, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: п, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: у, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: с, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: к, категория: LowercaseLetter
Символ: !, категория: OtherPunctuation
```

---

Стандарт Unicode, на котором основывается классификация, меняется со временем, так что и результаты, возвращаемые функцией, могут измениться с установкой какого-нибудь сервис-пака. Впрочем, к часто используемым символам это предупреждение не относится: их классификация меняться будет вряд ли.